# Get filename from a file uploaded mule esb 3.6

Tags: java, file-upload, mule-studio

I'm trying to develop a rest layer using mule 3.6, where I receive a file upload throug a POST method.

I've created the following flow:

```
<flow name="post:/campaigns/{campaignId}/files:multipart/form-data:api-config">
    <logger message="#[flowVars.nameFile]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <foreach collection="#[message.inboundAttachments]" doc:name="Foreach">
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\valter.gomes\Desktop\Nova pasta" outputPattern="#[message.outboundProperties]" connector-ref="File" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        </foreach>

</flow>
```

But I'm not able to get the name of uploaded file. I've tried : `#[message.outboundProperties.filename] ,   #[message.inboudProperties.filename] , #[header:filename]`

But stack trace is:

```
    Message               : Failed to route event via endpoint:   `enter code here`DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=file:///C:/Users/valter.gomes/Desktop/Nova%20pasta/, connector=FileConnector
{
  name=File
  lifecycle=start
  this=7f3f15d8
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[file]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint..C.Users.valter.gomes.Desktop.Nova pasta', mep=ONE_WAY, properties={outputPattern=#[header:filename]}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: DataHandler
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Expression Evaluator "header" with expression "outbound:filename" returned null but a value was required. (org.mule.api.expression.RequiredValueException)
  org.mule.expression.ExpressionUtils:235 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/expression/RequiredValueException.html)
2. Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=file:///C:/Users/valter.gomes/Desktop/Nova%20pasta/, connector=FileConnector
{
  name=File
  lifecycle=start
  this=7f3f15d8
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[file]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint..C.Users.valter.gomes.Desktop.Nova pasta', mep=ONE_WAY, properties={outputPattern=#[header:filename]}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: DataHandler (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
  org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageDispatcher:117 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.expression.RequiredValueException: Expression Evaluator "header" with expression "outbound:filename" returned null but a value was required.
    at org.mule.expression.ExpressionUtils.getPropertyInternal(ExpressionUtils.java:235)
    at org.mule.expression.ExpressionUtils.getPropertyWithScope(ExpressionUtils.java:63)
    at org.mule.expression.ExpressionUtils.getPropertyWithScope(ExpressionUtils.java:46)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Please, someone have any idea about how to get this filename using file:outbound-endpoint? Or is there another way to do this?

Thanks for your attention,

Valter Gomes

Answer (score 0):

The `file:outbound-endpoint` doesn't store the file name it's created in any property.

But, it can receive a file name via an outbound property name called `filename`. So you can assign this name upfront (for example using a random UUID) and set it as an outbound property for the endpoint to pick it up.

Reference: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.6.2/transports/file/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/file/FileMessageDispatcher.java#L58-L63